# How to add Camel properties component to camel context?

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

I'm currently trying to add properties component with location set to my properties file to use properties placeholders in my project:

```
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:properties.properties");
context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

But addComponent() function expects Component type argument, not PropertiesComponent even though PropertiesComponent extends the DefaultComponent class. I've added this dependency to pom.xml to use it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-properties</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

and also added the resources tag:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

The error I get looks like this:

> java: incompatible types: org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent cannot be converted to org.apache.camel.Component

I have no idea what causes it, please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Why relying on a milestone version? Which version of Camel do you want to use?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I'm using 3.16, I just copied the dependency from the Maven repository. There was no dependency for 3.16, I just used the newest one.

Comment: There is no dependency for 3.16 because it is now part of camel-base which means that you need to remove this dependency to fix your problem as it is probably due to a version conflict

Comment: I've added it to check if it change anything. Now I removed it and I get the same error.

Comment: Try this instead `context.getPropertiesComponent().setLocation("classpath:properties.properties");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertiesComponent` is a very special component thus there are dedicated methods like [`setPropertiesComponent`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#setPropertiesComponent(org.apache.camel.spi.PropertiesComponent)) and [`getPropertiesComponent()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#getPropertiesComponent()) in the Camel context to manage it that you should use instead.

Your code should rather be something like the following code:

```
// create the properties component
PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
pc.setLocation("classpath:properties.properties");

// add properties component to camel context
context.setPropertiesComponent(pc);
```

Or simply `context.getPropertiesComponent().setLocation("classpath:properties.properties")`