How to make Apache Camel set component options using properties file
In my Apache Camel code I've set up a properties component as follows:
// ...
PropertiesComponent propertiesComponent = new PropertiesComponent();
propertiesComponent.setLocation("component.properties");
context.setPropertiesComponent(propertiesComponent);
context.start();

And then in the component.properties file, I've written:
camel.component.activemq.brokerURL=myserver:616161

My expectation was that when I created my ActiveMQ route, it would try to send messages to the brokerURL specified in my properties file, but I see it is still using localhost:616161 (the default value). I know I can explicitly set this through the Java code, but is there a way to just set it in the properties file, and then when I create the route it will use the properties automatically?

Would be using application.properties an option instead? In that property file you can include the property and it would be correctly set in the context. Also this thread may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71769039/how-to-add-camel-properties-component-to-camel-context
